# Can I copy a Postgresql Large Object on the db server?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, oid

I've got data in a large object, now I want to make a copy of it so I can append to it while keeping the copy of the original.  Is there any JDBC call or SQL statement I can use to cause that to happen?

From every resource I have found, it seems I have to actually read all the data to my client and write it out again to get the copy.  I'd much prefer to save the round trip.

Answer (score 4):

**A large object can be copied/cloned with two queries** if you know its `oid`.

```sql
INSERT INTO pg_largeobject_metadata (lomowner, lomacl) 
  SELECT lomowner, lomacl
  FROM pg_largeobject_metadata
  WHERE oid = <my_old_oid>
RETURNING oid AS my_new_oid;

INSERT INTO pg_largeobject (loid, pageno, data)
  SELECT <my_new_oid>, pageno, data
  FROM pg_largeobject
  WHERE loid = <my_old_oid>;
```

`my_old_oid` is the large object's known oid
`my_new_oid` is the oid returned by the first insert statement

[pg_large_object reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-largeobject.html)
[Object Type Identifier (oid) reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-oid.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [server-side lo_import and lo_export](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/lo-funcs.html) functions. You will have to move the data from the database to the filesystem and back again, but at least it's the server's filesystem, not the client's.